# Sum column data model property

Tags: django, python-3.x

plz i need your help, i cant sum RESTE the return of model property ,
tried lot of methods but no success.
have you any idea about that ?

i'm using django framework 2.2

```
class Reglement(models.Model):
    """Model definition for Reglement."""

    # TODO: Define fields here
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    montant = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    date_reglement = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    date_expiration = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    actif = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    abonnement = models.ManyToManyField(Abonnement)

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Reglement."""
        verbose_name = 'Reglement'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Reglements'

    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of Reglement."""
        return f'{self.client} {self.montant}'

    @property
    def get_tarif(self):

        data = self.abonnement.values_list('tarif',)
        newData = ""
        if len(data) > 1:
            list_data = []
            for i in data:
                for j in i:
                    list_data.append(j)

            newData = sum(list_data)
        else:
            newData = data[0][0]
        total = newData - self.montant
        return total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Sum` aggregation function.

```
def get_tarif(self):            
    return self.abonnement.aggregate(val=models.Sum('tarif'))['val']
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you think that aggregations don't work with m2m fields? Just try the code.

Comment: no it works good but in this case the client may have more than one abonnement and i use the get_farif function to get abonnement.tarif and sum if there many.  the probleme is that the abonnement.tarif isn't field in data base, its just a function that calculate abonnement.tarif decimal fielf .

Comment: what i mean is that i use get_tarif() in a column when i loop in the template so i need the sum of get_tarif()

Answer (score 0):

```
def payement(request):
newprix = 0
reglements = Reglement.objects.all()
malist = []
for i in reglements:
    if i.get_tarif() > 0:

        malist.append(i.get_tarif())
data = sum(malist)
```

[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrOre.png)

its done thanks a lot